# Android:Mapping json values to pojo

Tags: android, json, jackson, gson, pojo

I am trying to map `JSON` values to POJO using `GSON`. When I try to get object back from `JSON` string all the variables are set to null.
here is my code

**Pojo.java**

```
public class PatientSymptoms {

    private Integer AnalSymptomsMapId;
    private Integer SymptomId;
    private String Symptom;
    private Boolean IsRemoved;
    private Boolean IsSynced;
    private Boolean IsSentToPatient;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**Mapping code**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
PatientSymptoms symptoms = new PatientSymptoms();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String x =  gson.toJson(jsonObject);
symptoms = gson.fromJson(x,PatientSymptoms.class);
```

but `PatientSymptoms` object values are always null. This is the screen shot of the debugger

[image: debugger o/p]

**UPDATED** JSON RESPONSE

```
{
  "Success": true,
  "StatusCode": 0,
  "StatusMessage": "",
  "Data": [
    {
      "AnalSymptomsMapId": 250,
      "SymptomId": 95,
      "Symptom": "asdf",
      "IsRemoved": false,
      "IsSynced": false,
      "IsSentToPatient": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: implement Parcelable.

Comment: post your json please

Comment: response has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give us an example of the Json? (like an string)

```
(JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i).toString()
```

Anyway, I recomend you to use @SerializedName annotation from Gson to do the mapping:

https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html

Comment: yes it  was this String x =  gson.toJson(jsonObject); replaced with String x =  jsonObject.toString(); and it worked.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Make your Pojo.java as

```
    public class PatientSymptoms {

    private int AnalSymptomsMapId;
    private int SymptomId;
    private String Symptom;
    private boolean IsRemoved;
    private boolean IsSynced;
    private boolean IsSentToPatient;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

So, the default values will be those of primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make your Model Using [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

1. Choose Source type: `JSON`.
2. Annotation style: `Gson`.
3. Click Preview.

Then you have generated a Model Class for your `JSON`.

And Don't forget to implements `Parcelable`.

Comment: For such a short answer, Please comment it!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I must have 50 reputation to comment @AndiGeeky

Comment: Oh, you can copy some content from that link and make answer more descriptive then!!

Comment: You need to earn reputation by asking question if you have.

Comment: @ Malik Abu Qaoud: Anytime!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try out [Ion library by Koush](https://github.com/koush/ion)

**MODEL**

```
public class PatientSymptoms {

       private int AnalSymptomsMapId;
       private int SymptomId;
       private String Symptom;
       private boolean IsRemoved;
       private boolean IsSynced;
       private boolean IsSentToPatient;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**USAGE**

```
Ion.with(context)
   .load("http://example.com/api/patient")
   .as(new TypeToken<List<PatientSymptoms>>(){})
   .setCallback(new FutureCallback<List<PatientSymptoms>>() {
       @Override
       public void onCompleted(Exception e, List<PatientSymptoms> symptoms) {
            // Use the list of Patient Symtoms
    }
});
```

**Note**: The only thing you need to remember is the JSON keys should match the variable names in the POJO or MODEL.